# Speeding up the taxonomy term autocomplete

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax

I've noticed that the autocomplete on my taxonomy fields takes a long time to load existing terms when trying to tag a node. I have to type out the whole term name and wait a few seconds before autocomplete finds the existing term. Is this normal? If not, how can I speed this up? The ideal would be terms appearing as soon as I type a letter.

Comment: How many terms do you have? How long do normal page requests take? An autocomplete is a normal request which results in a full bootstrap, all modules are loaded and so on. So if your site is slow anyway, that will also affect autocomplete request. But multiple seconds really sounds slow.

Comment: Well the delay varies but I would just like to speed it up. Is that possible?

Comment: You can't just magically speed it up, it is slow for a reason. And to figure that out, start by answering my questions above...

Comment: The taxonomy autocomplete function executes just a query that finds all the items present in the {term_data} table, which contains all the taxonomy terms used in all the vocabularies. Apart from limiting the numbers of taxonomy terms, I don't see how the function could be speeded up. I agree with @Berdir that there is a problem that causes the queries to be slow, not just the taxonomy autocomplete query.